# C# .NET 4.6.1 WebRequest is missing data from POST call that I can see using Fiddler

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I am making a call to a third party API, let's just say https://app/api to post to.  Everything was working great, then I added another field to my request and it appears the post works but the acknowledgement back is stripping it out.  So I am essentially using Newtonsoft.Json to do the conversion of the JSON to a well formed object.  So basically I had an object like:

```
public class POCO
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public string name { get; set;}
   public DateTime promise_by {get; set;}
}
```

It was working fine until I added 'promise_by' and lo and behold I found out that my web response was stripping out the field.  Yet if I do this same call manually in Fiddler it works right away.  Now I have seen similar threads but I was curious WHAT you exactly should be looking for in Fiddler to update the WebRequest to?  Like an AHA that is usually it!

So far I have a code similar to this:

```
request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
request.UserAgent = "";
request.Method = verb;
request.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.Username + ":" + this._password)));
request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
```

Like I said it gets data, it just does not get ALL the data.  Yet I know the same credentials in Fiddler will work just fine to get me data.  I know just adding request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, got me a lot more detail back.  Here are pic examples of what I mean:

[image: Fiddler working]

CSharp:

[image: CSharp fails somewhere]

Comment: Post the content of `response.response`

Comment: @Gusman you are already seeing some of it in the bottom pic.

Comment: No, I can't see nothing but the parsed data by your browser, not the real JSON payload. Anyway, the format shown i think is not valid for a date in JSON. Change the type to string and i'm nearly sure it will work.

Comment: That was it, thanks man.